# Select a specific part of a string

Tags: java, arrays, string

I am new to programming, and currently studying intro to Java. My assignment for this week, asks for us to print out in a specific way for a list of courses. This is my code:

```
package u9a1_defineclassinstantiateobj;

import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author Staci
 */
public class U9A1_DefineClassInstantiateObj {
   
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        System.out.println("Staci's Copy");
        
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        String[][] courses = {
            {"IT1006", "IT4782", "IT4789", "IT4079", "IT2230", "IT3345", "IT2249"},
            {"6", "3", "3", "6", "3", "3", "6"}              
        };
        
            
        System.out.println("course Objects each has a code (e.g. IT1006) and credit hours (e.g. 6)");
        System.out.println("The number inside the [] is the display number");
        System.out.println("The number inside the () is the credit hours for the course");
        for(int i = 0; i < courses[0].length; i++ ) 
            System.out.println("[" + (i+1) + "]" + courses[0][i] + "(" + courses[1][i] + ")");
        
    }
    
}
```

I need to have, instead of all the course numbers per line, the first course (IT1006) for each line, without any of the [] and () numbers changing. I feel like it is something so simple, but I just cannot figure it out. Thank you for all your help and guidance.

Output:

[image]

Instead of having each course defined per line in the output, the course IT1006 should only be defined, while the line number and course credit remain the same.

Comment: `[1]IT1006(6)` instead you want `(IT1006) ` ??? is it ?

Comment: Please use code formatting for code and code snippets, structured documents like HTML/XML or input/output.  To do that, select the text and click the `{}` button at the top of the message posting/editing form. Also, don't include code comments inserted by the IDE. They are just noise.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question, you can simply change `courses[0][i]` to `courses[0][0]` like

```
System.out.println("[" + (i + 1) + "]" + courses[0][0] + "(" + courses[1][i] + ")");
```

which will then output

```
Staci's Copy
course Objects each has a code (e.g. IT1006) and credit hours (e.g. 6)
The number inside the [] is the display number
The number inside the () is the credit hours for the course
[1]IT1006(6)
[2]IT1006(3)
[3]IT1006(3)
[4]IT1006(6)
[5]IT1006(3)
[6]IT1006(3)
[7]IT1006(6)
```

I find it easier to reason about *formatted io*, in case I've misunderstood your request, or just to make it easier to read - I would do

```
System.out.printf("[%d]%s(%s)%n", i + 1, courses[0][0], courses[1][i]);
```

Then you can adjust your `[]` and `()` without additional escaping for the variables for your output.

Comment: Yes! I knew it was something so simple and I was just staring at it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you want only first data, remove the loop and add:

```
System.out.println("[" + (1) + "]" + courses[0][0] + "(" + courses[1][0] + ")");
```